# Can anyone give a brief example of how to develop windows forms application with c++ and writing code in a cpp file

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

Can anyone give a brief example of how to develop windows forms application with c++ and writing code in a cpp file

The question is,

do i have to write the whole code for runtime in the myform.h only,
can't i write any piece of code in the cpp or a c file?

Comment: Usually devstudio takes care of that, are you sure you're not in need of writing a bare win32 application ?

Comment: i just want a window to take input from the user and display a calculated value, whether it is win32 or windows forms or anything that can do it

Comment: what compiler are you using? this should work with any C modern compiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb384843(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in a C++ standard program, you can write your code in a cpp file, for exemple :

[image]

For the button event, let the prototy in the header file :

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
```

And then, in a C++ source file, you can do :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace <your_project_namespace>;

Void Form1::button1_Click(Object^  sender, EventArgs^  e)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    double input;

    if (Double::TryParse(this->textBox1->Text, input))
    {
        result = input * 2.5;
        this->label1->Text = "Result= " + result + ".";
    }
}
```

Don' forgot to include your Form header file and use the good namespace. See the result :

[image]